# Right adjoint preserves limits

Tags: category-theory

Let $F\dashv G:\mathbf C\to \mathbf D$ be an adjunction and $J:\mathbf I\to \mathbf {D}$ be a diagram; call $l_i$ the canonical arrow $\lim (J)\to J(i)$. Then $\lim (GJ)\cong G(\lim (J))$, and also, the canonical arrow $\lim (GJ)\to GJ(i)$ is $G(l_i)$: one can prove this quite directly.

However one can also use an abstract argument of this type: $$\mathbf C(C,\lim (GJ))\cong\lim (\mathbf C(C,GJ)) \cong\lim(\mathbf D(FC,J))\cong\mathbf D(FC,\lim J)\cong \mathbf C(C,G(\lim J)).$$ So $G(\lim (J)\cong \lim (GJ))$ as Yoneda embedding is fully faithful. *Is there an immediate way to see that $G$ preserves also the canonical arrows, when using this argument?* I've been thinking about it for a while but I ended up with nothing. Is this argument a "shortcut", that however makes difficult to prove the preservation of canonical arrows, or am I not seeing a natural way to deduce it? Thanks for any clarify.

*EDIT (after comments).*  Thee following bijection is natural in $-$, and  so $\operatorname{id}_{\lim (GJ)}$ is mapped to an isomorphism $f:\lim (GJ)\to G(\lim J)$, as Yoneda embedding is fully faithful: $$\mathbf C(-,\lim (GJ))\cong\lim (\mathbf C(-,GJ)) \cong\lim(\mathbf D(F-,J))\cong\mathbf D(F-,\lim J)\cong \mathbf C(-,G(\lim J)).$$

Denote by $\bar { }$ the adjunct of an arrow; also, denote the canonical arrows out of $\lim (GJ)$ by $\lambda_i$, and those out of $\lim J$ by $l_i$, $i\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf I)$. Now set $C=\lim (GJ)$:  $$\mathbf C(\lim (GJ),\lim (GJ))\cong\lim (\mathbf C(\lim (GJ),GJ) \cong\lim(\mathbf D(F(\lim (GJ)),J))\cong\mathbf D(F(\lim (GJ)),\lim(J))\cong \mathbf C(\lim (GJ),G(\lim (J)).$$ Tracking the identity we have: $$\operatorname{id}_{\lim (GJ)}\mapsto (\lambda_i)_{i\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf I)}\mapsto (\bar{\lambda_i})_{i\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf I)}\mapsto \bar \lambda \mapsto f. $$ I'm thinking of the limit of a diagram (of shape $\mathbf I$) as a subset of a product over $\mathbf I$ (I say it to make clear the notations in the second and third step above). Also, $\bar \lambda$ is by definition the arrow such that $l_i\circ \bar\lambda=\bar\lambda_i$. Since the last bijection is natural in the other variable as well: $$\lambda_i=\overline{\bar\lambda_i}=\overline{l_i\circ\bar \lambda}=G(l_i)\circ f.$$

Comment: Sure. Set $C = \lim G J$ and see what $\textrm{id}$ corresponds to.